# Reading integers from text files in java and then finding the median

Tags: java

I'm really stuck with this, not sure how to do it.

What I want to do is read as input a set of numbers from a text file.

For example.

```
4
1
2
3
4
```

The first line contains `N`, the count of numbers. `N` lines follow.

If N is even, then -->`N/2`. In this case 4/2 = 2. From that we find the 2nd smallest number of the list. This is the output.

If N is odd, then --> `N+1/2`, and do the same.

How do I do this? I have this so far but I don't know how to sort it and read it into an array.

I've stumbled my way onto this. I really am just taking shots in the dark.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class TestClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        // read number of data from system standard input. 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = br.readLine();
        int N = Integer.parseInt(line);
        // median sum 
        long SumMedians = 0;

        {
            int[] MyArray = new int[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                MyArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            }
        }

        // write output to system standard output 
        System.out.println(SumMedians % 100000);
        System.out.println(MyArray);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sort list and then find medium

```
Arrays.sort(MyArray); // use java collection sort
SumMedians = (N % 2 == 0) ? MyArray[N/2] : MyArray[(N+1)/2];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your number is in a file why are you reading from System.in ?

Check [this tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/read_a_textfile_in_java.html) on how to open and read a file line by line.

Read the data into a string and then use [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) method to parse them as integers and store them in array as you parse them.

If your integers are separated by spaces do a [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and then do an [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Once you have the data in array on integers, sort the array by using [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5b%5d%29)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        int[] numbers = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }

        long sumOfTheMedians = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
            int[] slicedArray =  Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, 0, n + 1);
            Arrays.sort(slicedArray);
            sumOfTheMedians += medianForArray(slicedArray);
        }

        System.out.println(sumOfTheMedians % 100000);

    }

    private static int medianForArray(int[] numbers) {
        int n = numbers.length - 1;  //we have table from 0 to N - 1, not from 1 to N
        return (n % 2 == 0) ? numbers[(n+1)/2] : numbers[n/2] ;
    }
}
```

I deduced this solution from your discription and code and also I found this http://bit.ly/1hQhng9. It can be written much better, I know, but this is only a draft.

Comment: And yes, its for a hackerearth problem :) trying to work out how to make it faster now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first line of the input file is the number of elements (n) that follow, and the next n numbers are the numbers of the set whose median is to be deduced, one would write something like following:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Median
{
  public Median()
  {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get("/Users/Path/To/Input.txt")))
    {
      int numberOfElements = scanner.nextInt();

      int[] numbers = new int[numberOfElements];

      for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; ++i)
      {
        numbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
      }

      Arrays.sort(numbers);

      int medianIndex = ((numberOfElements % 2 == 0 ?
        numberOfElements : numberOfElements + 1) >> 1) - 1;

      System.out.println(numbers[medianIndex]);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new Median();
  }
}
```